# Libgdx | Should I dispose my assets in the pause and recreate them in the resume?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am creating game for android, and have some confusion. I haven't screen a clear answer to my question. People say I should create my assets in the show method, and dispose of them in the dispose. So, when should I call the screens dispose method? If the user goes home (on android/ios), should I dispose of anything? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code?  You might also want to take a stab at where you think the `dispose()` call might go and someone can tell you if it looks right.  It's hard to guess these things =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispose method is called by libGDX, you don't have to call that yourself. You don't have to do anything related to assets in your `pause` and `resume` methods.

Note that your asset management depends on your design. But usually you *don't* create the assets in the `Screen#show` method, but instead use a dedicated loading screen for that.

Comment: So I only have to dispose of stuff when I switch screens?

Comment: No, you typically use the same assets amongst screens.

Comment: Yes but what about something like a stage?

Comment: You can share the same `SpriteBatch` amongst multiple `Stage`s.

Comment: So that is the only thing that disposing a stage does?

Comment: Well there is also box2d stuff, and shaperenderers etc... So where should these be disposed of in the play if the player goes to the main menu? I know that the screen has a dispose, but where should I call that method?

Comment: Anything that you create in the `show` that needs to be destroyed can be destroyed in the `hide` method.

Comment: If the user leaves the app, then hide is called, right? How would the objects be re instantiated when the user goes back into the app?

Comment: No, hide is called when you change the screen, see http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html#hide--. Note that you can better ask a new question if you have a new question, instead of using the comments for that.

Comment: New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194583/libgdx-dispose-screen-in-applicaionlistener-or-from-screens-hide-method

Comment: Are you sure that `dispose` method is called by libGDX? Because there is a note in Screen's javadoc `Note that {@link #dispose()} is not called automatically.`

Comment: The dispose method of the `ApplicationListener` (and thus `ApplicationAdapter` and `Game`) is called by libGDX. See also the life-cycle: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle. LibGDX does not manage your screens, so it can't call the dispose method on those. But since you said that you create the object in your `show` method, that implies that the life-cycle of those objects are as long as the screen is visible, which is until `hide` is called. So you don't have to do anything in your screen `dispose` method, because you are not managing your screens.